# Adding multiple rows by script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have this simple Google Sheets script that adds a row after every already existing one. What do I have to change to for example add 12 rows?

```
function addRows(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();

  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();

  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows*2 - 1; i+=2) {

   sheet.insertRowAfter(i);

  }

}
```

Comment: This was asked on StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44695360/appending-multiple-rows-to-spreadsheet-google-apps-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to change your script. You could use [insertRows(nowIndex, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsrowindex-numrows) among other methods.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I found there the answer I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

My script below helps to add 1 new row above the row 2 but I was thinking to assign a pop up window asking how many rows to add and them run the script based on the number given.

```
function addRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getActiveRange();
  var R = range.getRowIndex();
  
sheet.insertRowsBefore(2,1);
  
}

function onOpen() {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp. getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Add Row').addItem('Insert','addRow').addToUi();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('addnewrow');
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  sheet.insertRowAfter(row);
}
```