# How to increase the number of rows of every table from 20 to 40 in a Google Docs file easily?

Tags: google-docs

This is the [file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/135rfzpr_gxWUkPnvrJesKK2D9LDdBX_1/edit?rtpof=true&sd=true). It is supposed to be a worksheet.

There are lots of tables in the file. Each table has 20 blank rows (for 20 students). I need 40 blank rows (for 40 students).

Adding the rows manually is a menially repetitive task. I found a relatively easy method. Select the 20 rows using the mouse, and then right click. Then an option comes up asking if I want to add 20 rows below or not, but it is still a cumbersome process to repeat for all the tables. How do I accomplish this task more easily?

**Edit:**

I don't know the Apps Script language, but still I stupidly tried the following code:

```
function myFunction() {      

for (let table in DocumentApp.getTables()) {      

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {              
table.insertTableRow(20); 

}   

}
```

It did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding multiple rows by script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115580/adding-multiple-rows-by-script)

Comment: @graham that's for Sheets, not for a Docs table.

Comment: You can probably do it easily with a Google Apps Script. Is that an option for you?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. This doesn't look like a practical, detailed question. Please check out [tour] and [ask]. P.S. You can use add-ons and Google Apps Script to extend Google Docs features. The [Google Docs Editors Help Center](https://support.google.com/docs) has an article about this, and the Google Docs app and the Google Docs editor have a Help menu that could make it easy to find. If you need further help, please [edit] the question to make it a good fit for this site.

Comment: @YisroelTech Yes, that is indeed an option for me. Do you have the code?

Comment: I can write it, but the question is now closed. Try to revise it and request to reopen. If it'll be open, I'll try to add the code.

Comment: I don't know how to further edit the question. I just asked what I needed to ask. On a side note, I tried the following;

`function myFunction() {
  
  for (let table in DocumentApp.getTables()) {

    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      
      table.insertTableRow(20);
} 

}`

But it didn't work :-(

Comment: Why is this a side note?... Add this to your question. Try to reword it. IDK

Comment: I kindly remind you that this platform is not intended for requesting basic usage guidance, as such information can easily be found in the tour or get-started documentation of the corresponding web application. Additionally, posting formulas and script requests is not suitable here. For those who want to learn more about Google Apps Script, I recommend visiting https://developers.google.com/apps-script. Furthermore, the guide to extending Google Docs using Apps Script found at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs may be helpful.

Comment: By the way, Google Apps Script is not a language; it's a platform that includes a web application to create and edit scripts, among other things; it uses JavaScript as the programming language and includes services that make it easy to automate Google Docs, etc.

Comment: Also, remember that this community has  "a third place", the [chat]; it might be helpful to provide and receive help (cc @YisroelTech)